# error setting metadata for a tmp file created in the copy local process

Tags: docker, docker-build

I'm running a docker build on *Ubuntu 23.10* on *Docker version 24.0.5, build ced0996* and it's producing an empty (0 byte) `.tmp.`+rand file in the process then throwing an error that it cannot set the metadata for it when trying to copy it locally:

```
ERROR: failed to solve: error from receiver: error setting metadata for
build/.tmp.680872741: lchown build/.tmp.680872741: operation not permitted
```

My `artifacts.Dockerfile` looks like:

```
# use the build image as a transient container for the build
FROM release-build AS build

# build in the home folder
WORKDIR /home/project

# copy the assets and dependencies into the build images source directory
COPY build/ .

# build the component
#RUN make project 1>>build.txt 2>>build.txt

# copy the object, dependencies, and entire build to the local file system
FROM scratch
COPY --from=build /home/project /
```

The actual `make` is commented out while diagnosing this issue indicating that this `tmp` file is being created by docker.  The build is being run like:

```
sudo cat artifacts.Dockerfile | docker build --no-cache --file - --output type=local,dest=build .
```

and the output looks like:

```
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                      0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 723B                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/release-build:latest                   0.0s
 => [build 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/release-build                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 26.09kB                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [build 2/3] WORKDIR /home/project                                              0.0s
 => [build 3/3] COPY build/ .                                                             0.0s
 => [stage-1 1/1] COPY --from=build /home/project /                                       0.0s
 => ERROR exporting to client directory                                                   0.0s
 => => copying files 1.89kB                                                               0.0s
------
 > exporting to client directory:
------
ERROR: failed to solve: error from receiver: error setting metadata for build/.tmp.680872741:
lchown build/.tmp.680872741: operation not permitted
```

Type `tmp` file is not present before the build, but is present after the failure - i.e. it copied locally then the attributes failed.  I've tried with and without `sudo`, I've tried adding `--chown 1000:1000` (matches my local ids) to the final COPY, tried without the `cat` to docker cache bypass.  It seems the `COPY build/ .` is where this 0-byte `.tmp.` file is being created as commenting that out avoids the file.  I tried changing that COPY to just copy a single file in and that `tmp` file is still created.

I'm at a loss as to how to avoid this `tmp` file creation, or its copy, or the attribute error.  Anyone have insights?  Thanks.